# New Azure Billing System

Tags: azure

Suddenly, my Azure Subscription page is not showing data anymore.  It said it has been deprecated.  How do I get it to work again?

[image: Azure Subscription - Deprecated Warning Message]

Comment: Azure is having serious issues, see https://twitter.com/AzureSupport as the status page is semi-broken at the moment.

Comment: True.  We are having lots of issues this morning.